# GMSMapView wont initialize

Tags: viewcontroller, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsmapview

I have a GMSMapView on my storyboard

```
       @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GMSMapView *gmsMapViewUI;
```

Using the instructions I am unable to get my this mapView to update to the new coordinates. This had been working for me in the past but I have since restructured the function and seem to be missing some crucial detail to get the map to load correctly again. There are so few lines to my call I must have missed one thing or another. Google SDK doesn't give me any clear information either.

```
        GMSCameraPosition *newCam=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:33 longitude:122 zoom:16];
        self.gmsMapViewUI=[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.gmsMapViewUI.bounds camera:newCam];
        self.gmsMapViewUI.delegate=self;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the camera only instead of throwing away the GMSMapView created by the storyboard? Like

```
self.gmsMapViewUI.camera = newCam;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this to move to a new cameraPosition.

```
[self.gmsMapViewUI animateToCameraPosition:newCam];
```